# How to use regex optionally filter out some word at the end

Tags: regex

I have strings like this

```
/city/town/movie/M-12345
/city/town/movie/M-23456/shown
/city/town/movie/M-34567/coming
```

i would like to have a regex to filter out movie id if the path is end with id

```
(?<path1>.*)(?:(\/M-[0-9]+$))
```

would like path1 to be

```
/city/town/movie
/city/town/movie/M-23456/shown
/city/town/movie/M-34567/coming
```

however actual result is only

```
/city/town/movie
```

any idea what i did wrong?

Comment: "however actual result is only..." - which language are you using ? please post the code that you're running. Regex has different flavors!

Comment: BTW, why not keep it simple, and filter out any *match* to `\d+$` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty simple like this if you're using `PHP`:

```
<?php
$urls = array('/city/town/movie/M-12345','/city/town/movie/M-23456/shown','/city/town/movie/M-34567/coming');
$regex = '~M-\d+$~';

$cleaned = preg_replace($regex, '', $urls);
print_r($cleaned);

/*
Array
(
    [0] => /city/town/movie/
    [1] => /city/town/movie/M-23456/shown
    [2] => /city/town/movie/M-34567/coming
)
*/    

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following pattern:

```
^.+(?=\/M-\d+$)|^.+(?!\/M-\d+$)
```

https://regex101.com/r/F76E3f/1